# SQL CASE query prioritization

Tags: query, syntax

I'm doing a pokemon sql table and created a new column named capacity_difference to determine the collectability of each pokemon in the table. However, when I want to use CASE query to categorize them, the outcomes only show the ELSE condition for every log. Can someone please tell me how to fix the query?

My queries are as follow:

```
ALTER TABLE pokemon add capacity_difference INTEGER;

SELECT name, type_1, type_2, HP, (attack - defense) as capacity_difference from pokemon; 

SELECT name, type_1, type_2, HP, (attack - defense) as capacity_difference, 
  CASE 
    when capacity_difference > 90 then "collect asap"
    when  capacity_difference < 90 and capacity_difference > 50 then "good"
    when capacity_difference > 0 and capacity_difference < 50 then "okay"
    when capacity_difference > -10 and capacity_difference < 0 then "bad"
  ELSE "worse"
  END AS Collectability
FROM pokemon;
```

Comment: please tag your rdms and add some data to your query

Comment: Did you actually populate your new column with values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that renaming ( (attack - defense) as capacity_difference ) is not known at the time when your case expression is evaluated. I.e. Your case expression is evaluating the column `capacity_difference` which you have not assigned a value. I would suggest that you get rid of that column, and do:

```
SELECT name
     , type_1
     , type_2
     , HP
     , CASE when capacity_difference > 90 
            then "collect asap" 
            when capacity_difference < 90 and capacity_difference > 50 
            then "good" 
            when capacity_difference > 0 and capacity_difference < 50 
            then "okay" 
            when capacity_difference > -10 and capacity_difference < 0 
            then "bad" 
            ELSE "worse" 
       END AS Collectability 
FROM (
    SELECT (attack - defense) as capacity_difference
         ,  name
         , type_1
         , type_2
         , HP
    FROM pokemon
) AS t;
```

Comment: Hi Lennart! Thank you for the answer and it worked well! May I know what does the "AS t" part mean?

Comment: It's an alias for the derived table. It is not mandatory in the standard but some DBMS requires a name

Comment: Ohh I see. Appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

With mysql and mariadb, you can do

> ```
> CrEATE Table pokemon (name VARCHAR(19), type_1 VARCHAR(19), type_2 VARCHAR(19), HP INT, attack INT, defense INT);
> ```

> 

> ```
> INSERT INTO pokemon VALUES ('a','fire','water',20,4,2),('b','fire','water',20,67,2);
> ```

> ```
> SELECT name, type_1, type_2, HP, @capacity_diff := (attack - defense) as capacity_difference, 
>   CASE 
>     when @capacity_diff > 90 then "collect asap"
>     when  @capacity_diff < 90 and @capacity_diff > 50 then "good"
>     when @capacity_diff > 0 and @capacity_diff < 50 then "okay"
>     when @capacity_diff > -10 and @capacity_diff < 0 then "bad"
>   ELSE "worse"
>   END AS Collectability
> FROM pokemon;
> ```
>
> ```
> name | type_1 | type_2 | HP | capacity_difference | Collectability
> :--- | :----- | :----- | -: | ------------------: | :-------------
> a    | fire   | water  | 20 |                   2 | okay          
> b    | fire   | water  | 20 |                  65 | good
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ba848b02558017eb691b86b2e29ebfd6)*

Comment: Hi! I'm very new to SQL and can you please explain a little more on the VARCHAR()?

Comment: varchar is a datatype for characters and text, you can also use nvarchar or TXT, that dioesn't matter in zthe query. the user variable @capacity_diff is set before you make your CASE